# How to show that a equation is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be the set $W := \{(p,q,r,s) \in \mathbb{R}^{4} \mid  x+3y+4q=0 \}$. How can I show that $W$ is a vector space? Is $(6,8,6,4)$ in $W$? How and why?
Please do all the works I am really confused about it.

Comment: The *equation* is not a vector space. The *set of solutions* to the equation is a vector space.

Comment: @titt What do you have so far?

Comment: What the equation is telling you is a specific relationship betweeen three of the vector components.  What you are asked to show is whether the set W of vectors with this particular property has the properties of a vector space.  For instance, is the set closed under addition and scalar multiplication?  If you add two such vectors, does the new vector still have the properties in W?  If you multiply a vector in W by a non-zero number, is _that_ vector still a member of W?  And so forth...

Comment: i am confused because there is no z in the equation

Comment: That means that there is no restriction on the number for the z-component of the vectors in W.  The equation stipulates that $ \ x = -3y - 4q \ $, so a vector in W could be written as $ \ < -(3y + 4q) , y , z , q > \ $ .

Comment: x1+y1+4q1=0 and then x2+y2+4q2=0

Comment: then Cx1+cy1+c4q1=0

Comment: I forget the process and i also dont have the book to look so what should i do from here

Comment: Can u do the steps for me . I have an exam few hours later . And there will be question like this in the exam

Comment: You can find the properties of a vector space online nowadays.  You need to consider questions, for instance, such as: if $ \ < -(3y + 4q), y , z , q > \ $ is in W , is $ \ c \ \cdot < -(3y + 4q), y , z , q > \ $ also in W?  That's as far as I'll go for now.  (And the comments aren't supposed to be used as a chat-room...)

Comment: I am a new user

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, a minor LaTeX tip: `<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for *that meaning only*. When you want angle brackets, you need to use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: @titt maybe this link helps you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11609/show-that-this-is-a-vector-space-and-determine-the-dimension?rq=1

Comment: @Zev Chonoles  Thank you for the tip: I have started using it below.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the question: "How to show that a equation is a vector space?" is meaningless. An equation is an equation, a vector space is a set together with operations and together with a field of scalars, so you can see these are very different things. Now, you can discuss wether the set of solutions of an equation is a vector space or not (after all it's a set, and we can sum and multiply solutions by scalars in the obvious way).

Now, this set $W$ is obviously a vector space. The reason is because it's the kernel of a linear transformation. Indeed set $L : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ by the following $L(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_4$. Now your set $W$ is just $W = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid L(x)=0$}, and since the kernel of a linear transformation is indeed a vector subspace of the domain, it's obviously a vector space itself because $W=\ker L$.

To check wether $(6,8,6,4)$ is in $W$ you compute $L(6,8,6,4) = 6+2\cdot8+4\cdot4\neq0$ so it doesn't satisfy the condition $L(x) = 0$ and so it's not in $W$.

Comment: I think it would be more reasonable for the OP to check that the set of solutions $W$ satisfies the axioms of a vector space one by one instead of using kernels and an isomorphism theorem (which they might not be familiar with); OP seems new to vector spaces.

Comment: @anon, I've used this because I've answered a question of the same author a while ago about computing kernels. So I thought it would be good to make a little use of that.

Answer (score 1):

The two essential properties for a vector space W are that the "zero vector" should be a member and that if vectors $ \ \overrightarrow{v_1} \ $ and $ \ \overrightarrow{v_2} \ $ are in W , then any linear combination  $ a \  \overrightarrow{v_1} \ + \ b \ \overrightarrow{v_2} \ $ is also in W.

Since $ \ 0 \ + \ 3 \cdot 0 \ + \ 4 \cdot 0 \ = \ 0 \ , $ the vector $ \ \langle 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 \rangle \   $ is indeed in W.

For vectors $ \ \langle -(3y_1 + 4q_1) , y_1 , z_1 , q_1 \rangle $ and $ \ \langle -(3y_2 + 4q_2) , y_2 , z_2 , q_2 \rangle \ ,  $ is it the case that

$$  \langle  \ a \ [ -(3y_1 + 4q_1) ] \ + \ b \ [ -(3y_2 + 4q_2) ]  \  , ay_1 \ + \ by_2 \ , \  az_1 \ + \ bz_2 \ , \ aq_1  \ + \ bq_2  \ \rangle $$

is also in W?  Does it still satisfy the relationship between the first, second, and fourth components?  If so, then W is closed under linear combinations and is a vector space.